# Maximum values in Python dicationary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, max

I would like to have the maximum value per key in a Python dictionary.

```
dictionary = {"age": [25, 29], "coverage": [100, 45], "z_parameter": [23, 39]}
print(dictionary)
{'coverage': [100, 45], 'age': [25, 29], 'z_parameter': [23, 39]}
```

Desired output  is:

```
{'coverage': [100], 'age': [29], 'z_parameter': [39]}
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried, please? I'll show you mine if you show me yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
>>> d = {'coverage': [100, 45], 'age': [25, 29], 'z_parameter': [23, 39]}
>>> {key: [max(val)] for key, val in d.items()}
{'age': [29], 'z_parameter': [39], 'coverage': [100]}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dictionary = {"age": [25, 29], "coverage": [100, 45], "z_parameter": [23, 39]}

output = dict()
for key, value in dictionary.iteritems():
     output[key] = max(value)

>>> print(output)
{'age': 29, 'z_parameter': 39, 'coverage': 100}
```

If you need your values as a list you can do wrap it in square braces when assigning the value

```
output[key] = [max(value)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using dict comprehension :

```
{x:[max(y)] for x, y in dictionary.iteritems()}
```

Output :

```
{'age': [29], 'z_parameter': [39], 'coverage': [100]}
```